# Is my damaged passport still valid?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps, pakistani-citizens

Recently in Malaysia, an Immigration officer tried to pull out a stapled special pass slip from a visa page in my passport, and the got torn on the top right (as in picture). Luckily, there was no visa on either side; it is just a blank page.

I managed to get the torn part from officer, although he didn't want to give it back to me. Now, I am bit worried whther my passport is valid or was invalidated by this damage.

I attached the torn part with a glue stick; should I staple some eVisa to hide the tear mark?

[image][image]

Comment: If you are concerned about the validity of your​passport you should be able to get it replaced.

Comment: purely one man's opinion, it should be fine.  replacing a passport is an expensive scam that governments run: as DJ says you can replace it if you're worried but the expense is a shame.  unfortunately it's up to "other countries", not "your country" on whether they accept it!  So it's impossible really to absolutely know what will happen.

Comment: @Fattie What makes passport an expensive scam? Is it supposed to be free?

Comment: I wouldn't bother to pay the $110 for a replacement US passport but thats me. I've used a passport which was slightly defaced for years

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my passport damaged?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48991/is-my-passport-damaged)

Comment: Anecdotal, but I accidentally ripped a visa out of my passport once and the staple tore through the page. I continued to use that passport for another 6-7 years without issue. (US passport)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my personal experience. 
My passport has been damaged in a similar way by a US immigration officer four years ago, although it's slightly smaller : [image: my passport]

It has not been a problem for getting a US visa, a Russian visa, and for travelling to Europe, the US, Canada and Brazil. The only time someone noticed it is when flying Emirates Airlines to Japan : during check-in they made me sign a waiver saying that it's not Emirates' fault that my passport is damaged, in case I'm refused entry because of it. But it wasn't a problem at all when entering Japan.

Comment: Additional info: when leaving Russia by train to Finland, the immigration officer seemed suspicious about it and asked her colleague, but apparently the colleague said it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described and the shown in the images, your passport has not been invalidated. Damage sustained while travelling is of concern but, fortunately, it is a corner torn from an unmarked page.

Generally, passports are automatically invalidated when they are significantly damaged, particularly when the data and chip portions are no longer clear and readable.

If you're still on your travels, it shouldn't be necessary to replace your passport although, if you're still concerned, you can always stop in at your country's nearest embassy or consulate for verification. Otherwise, wait until you return home to ask whether a torn page merits the expense of replacement.